# Website runs executable program

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My website runs a local .exe file (generates some data), when a user clicks a certain link.

I would like to know how to do the following

- what command to use to run the .exe?
- where should I store the .exe and still maintain security?

I use .net 4 c#

Comment: it generates some other text files.

Comment: What are your security constrains? What kind of environment are you running in? Any suggestion on security will have to be based on this information to be meaningful.

Comment: It's a shared hosting env. I want the generated files stored in the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that I use in one of my applications:

```
 var p = new Process();
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapFfmpegPath();
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = "arguments go here :)";
 p.Start();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

As for the executable itself, I created a directory in my project and put the exe in that directory. The `MapFfmpegPath` method looks something like this.

```
public static string MapFfmpegPath(this HttpServerUtility server)
{
  return "\"" + server.MapPath("/CoolPathHere/ffmpeg.exe") + "\"";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this works in MVC, but give it a shot:

```
// Process class resides in System.Diagnostics namespace
Process myProcess = Process.Start("...");
myProcess.WaitForExit();
// todo : process your data
```

Comment: how should i reference the .exe? and where should I put it?

Comment: Need help with this part. Process.Start("...");

Comment: `Server.MatPath()` should do the trick. It works in `ASP.NET`, not sure about `MVC`.